# Create a new "portable" server in SQL Server 2014 and view it in the same SQL Server Management Studio instance of other servers

Tags: sql-server, server, linked-server

I have the server

```
DESKTOP-TI7M67V\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server 12.0.2269 - DESKTOP-TI7M67V\joe)
```

It is a SQL Server 2014 database engine using Windows authentication.

I need to create a new server, database engine with SQL Server authentication this time, that I need to connect and view into the same SQL Server Management Studio instance I use for my server by now, since I need to create queries involving both.

I've seen that I can do it with linked server feature, but I need to create and setup the new server correctly.

The access to this new server, obtainable through SQL Server authentication, must have different authentication parameters than the other one already existing, if a user doesn't have them, he would be able to access the old server, but not the new. The access of both servers has to happen in the same SQL Server Management Studio instance.

Plus, the databases files of this new server must be portable. For portable, I mean that all its files (that make it work) must be able to be put in a custom directory on two pcs, with SQL Server 2014 already installed on both, and be copyable and pastable, e.g on a pendrive, in order to be transferred from a PC to the other. That's for maintain synchronization between two different physical users workplaces in which the database will be used, workplaces that for the moment are not directly interfaceable with a single, fixed, detached and interconnected source on which place the database.

My question is how to create a new server that would have these features.

Comment: IF you've set up SQL Server with both SQL Server and Windows authentication, you could use this one instance with both authentication schemes. Otherwise you need to set up a new SQL Server instance with a unique instance name and the appropriate authentication schemes enabled at the time of the installation.

Comment: Not certain what you mean with "portable" but I think you need some direction in designing a muiti-user system. Designing a system based on using a sql server back-end is not a "portable" solution - just copying files around will not be sufficient to install and use it on some random machine. But I also think you have some basic misunderstandings about what SSMS is and how to create/use multiple databases.